# Advancing semi-monopoly game for local and network capabilities

Tags: java, sockets

Our uni project is a semi-monopoly game.

For its first phase, the game had to support exactly 2 players, taking turns to play on same machine. Interactions with game were through standard input/output.

Now, for the second phase, we're to advance our game in order to support local and network programming and also being capable of handling up to 4 players. In local situation, players, that are now up to 4, take turns to play on a computer and in network part, client-server model shall be used, the game should also support chat interface. Also GUI is mandatory for either of these situations.

I'm looking for detailed explanations and hints over how to implement these features. Shall we first build the local mode and then move to network one? How can we handle both local and network modes? Are there any good tutorials about this situation which I explained and if there, would you please hand it over to me?

I searched the net but couldn't find much appropriate stuff. Detailed explanations on how to continue from now on is highly appreciated.

Comment: what you have tried till now buddy?

Comment: I have read about socket programming a bit. GUI designing is not a big deal to us. Some panel classes and frames and ActionListeners implemented on them. A routine work is expected in this field. My idea is to implement up to 4 players capability for now, which is really easy as in first phase, we had 2 players. Just some small changes in logic part and everything will be fine. But what bugs me is how to differ local and network modes and how to handle network mode :-/
@abhijeetdhumal

Comment: Your question is a bit too broad to be in line with SO's standards. I suggest you start trying something and the ask a number of more specific questions (e.g. "how do I instatiate a TCP socket in Java?" or similar). TRying to give you some directions: try to first implement the local mode, but try to abstract in an interface the part that "sends" the data to other players. Then when you move to remote you can re-implement it over socket, and have a menu or something that chooses which implementation to use.

Answer (score 0):

If you are searching of goggling "multiplayer monopoly in java" online, most probably your search will be futile. You have to scrutinize the features in the program and search it specifically.

The game rules will be somewhat similar for single player and multiplayer but the model will be different.

A server will be needed to handle all clients' request (for example decide who's turn is it now).

I will suggest writing a small program to test out a client and server with socket programming first. (For this you can easily get it online)

Make sure the client and server can communicate by sending messages to each other. However, a single threaded socket program will most probably be half-duplex (you can either send message OR receive message. You cannot do both at the same time).

To be able to send and receive message concurrently, you can implement a multi-threaded socket program. It is also good to learn how to broadcast message to all other clients.

Once you are able to establish `1 to 1` , `1 to many` and `many to 1` communication, the rest of the program implementation will be similar to a 2 player hot-seat game.

> I'm looking for detailed explanations and hints over how to implement these features. Shall we first build the local mode and then move to network one?

You most probably already have the local mode built up since your project is done by phase. I will suggest you to try out the socket programming first. Make sure you have a working socket program, then embed your game rules into it.

> How can we handle both local and network modes?

You only have to handle network mode. A program with network can handle local as well (for example loading the localhost ip 127.0.0.1). Of course you can also keep your current version and use it for local mode.